# Code not working to disable items in spinner android

Tags: android, material-design, android-spinner

Dropdown list for country and city:

[image: Dropdown list for country and city]

I want to make a spinner in android just like this attached image. For example, you select the list and you can choose any city from the country.Only the cities should be clickable and can be stored from the list. The country name should not be clickable.Having problem in disabling some of the items from the spinner.
This is the xml for the spinner.

```
 `<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/districtSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="District"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:theme="@style/MyEditText"

      />`
```

And this is the code:

```
`Spinner DistrictBetterSpinner;
 String[] District_Spinner = new String[]{"Punjab", "Rawalpindi", "Attock",      "Faisalabad", "Chakwal", "Bhakkar", "Jhelum", "Multan", "Chiniot"
        , "Bhawalpur", "Jhelum", "Gujrat", "Gujranwala", "Lahore", "Mianwali", "Khyber Pakhtunkhwa (KPK)", "Abbotabad", "Haripur", "Kohat",
        "Sindh", "Hyderabad", "Jacobabad", "Balochistan", "Awaran", "Gawadar", "Federally Administered Tribal Areas", "Khyber Agency",
        "Mohmat Agency", "Azad Jammu and Kashmir", "Neelum", "Bagh", "Gilgit Baltistan", "Skardu", "Astore"};
  List<String> spinnerlist;
  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_post); 
  DistrictBetterSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.districtSpinner);
  spinnerlist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(District_Spinner));
  arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddPostActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerlist);
  public boolean isEnabled(int position){
  if (position == 0 || position==1) {
  return false;
  } else {
  return true;
  }
  }

@Override
    public View getDropDownView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView spinnerTextView = (TextView) view;
        if (position == 0) {
            // Set the disable item text color
            spinnerTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            spinnerTextView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
        return view;
    }
}

;

 arrayadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
DistrictBetterSpinner.setAdapter( arrayadapter);
```

`

Comment: Not really sure what is your question. Please add additional details and clarify the question. Thanks!

Comment: I want to make some items clickable and some unclickable. Forexample country name should be not clickable but cities name should be clickable

Comment: I have edited and question. Please have a look.

Comment: In either the `getDropDownView` or the `getView` method, set the appropriate (i.e. when it is a city) view's `onClickListener`. i.e. '<view>,setOnClickListener(.....)'

Answer (score 0):

I think the following may be what you are after (new lines added to `getDropDownView` after you set the `TextColor` for Cities to grey):-

```
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView spinnerTextView = (TextView) view;
        if (position == 0) {
            // Set the disable item text color
            spinnerTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            spinnerTextView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            spinnerTextView.setOnclickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //YOUR ONCLICK HANDLING CODE HERE
                }
            });
        }
        return view;
    }
```

*P.S. in my comment above I mentioned `getView` as an alternative. It isn't as that's the selection view rather than the dropdown (got mixed up with `ListViews`).*

Looking more closely at your Answer and Code. I see that you haven't got anywhere really. So here's a rudimentary example based upon your code.

First a new layout file for an entry in the dropdown list (*I've also cheated a little and used this for the selected entry, you probably have a separate layout for each*). This is **spinner_item.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinnerTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you want customised features you should probably have a custom adapter (which is what you appeared to be attemtping in your code). The adapter handles placing the data (arrayList in your case) into the views used by the spinner (the term used is inflate). So here's the custom adapter which I've placed into it's own file. This is **MyArrayAdapter.java** :-

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Mike092015 on 31/10/2016.
 */
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private TextView district;
    private ArrayList<String> districts;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Activity context, int layout, ArrayList<String> districts) {
        super(context, layout, districts);
        this.context = context;
        this.districts = districts;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertview;
        if (v == null) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.spinner_item,parent,false);
        }
        district = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTextView);
        district.setText(districts.get(position));
        district.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"You clicked me",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertview;
        if (v == null) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.spinner_item,parent,false);
        }
        district = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTextView);
        district.setText(districts.get(position));
        return v;
    }
}
```

Note the `onClickListener` in the `getDropDownView` this is where you catch and handle the clicking of an entry (*in this case it just issues a toast*).

**activity_main.xml** (the layout that includes the spinner, little, if any different from your layout) is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Testing"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/districtSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="District"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Lastly the activity, to test this I've used MainActivity, so **MainActicity.java** is:-

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by Mike092015 on 3/06/2016.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner DistrictBetterSpinner;
    String[] District_Spinner = new String[]{"Punjab", "Rawalpindi", "Attock", "Faisalabad", "Chakwal", "Bhakkar", "Jhelum", "Multan", "Chiniot"
            , "Bhawalpur", "Jhelum", "Gujrat", "Gujranwala", "Lahore", "Mianwali", "Khyber Pakhtunkhwa (KPK)", "Abbotabad", "Haripur", "Kohat",
            "Sindh", "Hyderabad", "Jacobabad", "Balochistan", "Awaran", "Gawadar", "Federally Administered Tribal Areas", "Khyber Agency",
            "Mohmat Agency", "Azad Jammu and Kashmir", "Neelum", "Bagh", "Gilgit Baltistan", "Skardu", "Astore"};
    ArrayList<String> spinnerlist;
    MyArrayAdapter arrayadapter;

    DistrictBetterSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.districtSpinner);
    spinnerlist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(District_Spinner));
    arrayadapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.spinner_item,spinnerlist);
    arrayadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
    DistrictBetterSpinner.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
}
```

}

Note there are some changes but it is very much based upon your code.